# How to combine multiple NSString.CompareOptions in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm trying to combine multiple nsstring compare options in swift for use in the method `string.range(of:)`but I'm getting an error:

`Referencing operator function '|' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'NSString.CompareOptions' conform to 'BinaryInteger'`

This is how I'm creating the options:

```
        let options = NSString.CompareOptions.diacriticInsensitive | NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive
```

In objective-c this works fine but there's an error in swift. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`NSString.CompareOptions` is an `OptionSet` in Swift. You would use it using array literal syntax:

```
let options: NSString.CompareOptions = [
    .diacriticInsensitive,
    .caseInsensitive,
]
```

You should read more about OptionSets in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset

NSHipster also covers them well, and contrasts them with the raw integers used in Objective C: https://nshipster.com/optionset/